I need a formula for this situation
So, this is the situation I'm facing, need formula in column B & column C:



A
B
C
1
2
3
4
5
6




0.2
3/4/5
4
0.1
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.3


0.1
1
1
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.3
0.3


0.3
5/6
5.5
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.3
0.3



For column B:
For column A there is the answer already, and for column B is where I need the formula.
If A is 0.1, in column B the answer should return 1 in from the top row.
If A is 0.2 which we can find 3, 4 & 5 were also matching 0.2, column B need to show 3/4/5 to show all answers.
For column C:
Column C needs to get the average from column B, if in column B there is only 1 answer, then of course it will be the same number.
If column B have multiple answers, I want the average number from column B showing up in column C.
Also worth mentioning is that I don't want an array formula, I want formula which need to copy down the row as I might need to manually change the answer in column B or C, so I don't want the array formula breaks if I do so.
Thanks again for coming and helping!

This is a draggable formula as you requested. Enter this in B2 & it would fill both the joined value in B2 and average in C2.
=let(_filter,ifna(filter(D$1:I$1,D2:I2=A2)),
     hstack(join("/",_filter),average(_filter)))


It is filtering the header row in step 1 & then joining it in step 2 to furnish it as output
Incase you want B2 & C2 as separate formulas as well then this goes into B2:


 =let(_filter,ifna(filter(D$1:I$1,D2:I2=A2)),join("/",_filter))



and in C2:


=let(_filter,ifna(filter(D$1:I$1,D2:I2=A2)),average(_filter))



Omg thank you SO MUCH! It's amazing that you even have the separated version. And it is also so amazing to me that you guys can use 1 formula to fill up multiple rows/columns! Anyway thx again, I'm so grateful for your help!

@YuLunCHEN see What should I do when someone answers my question?
